# in arraylist data.size() showing 0 which i want to return

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, retrofit

please help me how to return data added which i'm using to set data to 
    cardview in recyclerview.
   i didn't understand why arraylist size returning zero.anyone please explain.

```
    private List<NotificationData> prepareData() {
    data = new ArrayList<>();
    data.clear();
    SharedPreferences prfs = getSharedPreferences("userdetails", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    String outletid = prfs.getString("outletid", "");
    String authkey = prfs.getString("authkey", "");
    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("http://xxxxxx-yyyyy.zzzz.com/api/v1/outlet/cpf-ghh/" + outletid + "/")
            .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();
    FuelwareInterface fuelwareInterface = retrofit.create(FuelwareInterface.class);
    Call<ResponseBody> responce_outlets;
    Log.d("authkeyssss", "onClick: "+authkey);
    responce_outlets = fuelwareInterface.getallindents(authkey);
    responce_outlets.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call, Response<ResponseBody> response) {

            if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                try {
                    String result = response.body().string();
                    Log.d("like", "***   " + result);
                    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(result);
                    JSONArray jsonObject1=jsonObject.getJSONArray("data");

                    Log.d("ghllwnmm", "________"+jsonObject1.length());
                    int i=jsonObject1.length();
                    data.clear();
                    for (int j=0;j<i;j++){
                        JSONObject jsonObject2=jsonObject1.getJSONObject(j);
                        NotificationData notificationData = new NotificationData(jsonObject2.getString("vehicle_number"),
                                jsonObject2.getString("indent_number"),jsonObject2.getString("id"),
                                jsonObject2.getString("fill_type"),jsonObject2.getString("product"),
                                jsonObject2.getString("fill_date"),jsonObject2.getString("status"),
                                jsonObject2.getString("litre"),jsonObject2.getString("amount"));
                        data.add(notificationData);
                    }
                    Log.d("lk000jhgfs", "prepareMovieData: "+data.size());
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Something Went Wrong",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<ResponseBody> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.d("failuremethods", "content   " + call.toString());
        }
    });
    Log.d("lkjhgfs", "prepareMovieData: "+data.size());
    return data;
}
```

data which i want to return showing size zero which i don't want.

Comment: Can you paste your Json response data here ?

Comment: im getting response correct logger with id lk000jhgfs returning size correctly but when returntype is setting data size was showing as 0.

Comment: did you debug the code ? i think some problem in the json response.
paste your exact response here

Comment: Are u getting any exception while parsing Json data ?

Comment: no see code once on responce i kept logd and at return statement i kept logd. in onresponce showing size as 3,at return showing size as 0

Comment: @Vishva Dave can u explain it clearly

Comment: You are working on multi thread, when you call responce_outlets.enqueue it will run in difference thread, but the method will return(not wait for the data response).  If you noited you can see that the log with TAG "lkjhgfs" will show before TAG "lk000jhgfs".  @rajan answer look like the right answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is `return` statement won't wait till `onResponse` method is called , so it will `return 0` immediately, if you want to get the `data`, pass an `interface` to `method` and use `callback` to post as in

**interface**

```
public interface ResultCallback{
   void onResult(List<NotificationData> data);
}
```

**Method**

```
private void prepareData(ResultCallback callback) { //< make it void
 // some code
   responce_outlets.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call, Response<ResponseBody> response) {

            if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                try {
                    String result = response.body().string();
                    Log.d("like", "***   " + result);
                    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(result);
                    JSONArray jsonObject1=jsonObject.getJSONArray("data");

                    Log.d("ghllwnmm", "________"+jsonObject1.length());
                    int i=jsonObject1.length();
                    data.clear();
                    for (int j=0;j<i;j++){
                        JSONObject jsonObject2=jsonObject1.getJSONObject(j);
                        NotificationData notificationData = new NotificationData(jsonObject2.getString("vehicle_number"),
                                jsonObject2.getString("indent_number"),jsonObject2.getString("id"),
                                jsonObject2.getString("fill_type"),jsonObject2.getString("product"),
                                jsonObject2.getString("fill_date"),jsonObject2.getString("status"),
                                jsonObject2.getString("litre"),jsonObject2.getString("amount"));
                        data.add(notificationData);
                    }

                    callback.onResult(data); //<this will push data back to caller

                    Log.d("lk000jhgfs", "prepareMovieData: "+data.size());
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Something Went Wrong",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<ResponseBody> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.d("failuremethods", "content   " + call.toString());
        }
    });
  //some code
}
```

**Calling method to get data**

```
prepareData(new ResultCallback(){
   @Override
   public void onResult(List<NotificationData> data){
      // log data.size you will get everything
   }
});
```

Comment: thanks a lot working fine,i wasted half a day trying by myself.

Comment: Glad I could help :) Happy coding!